# Return Value in Module Returns Null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

I'm attempting to create a module where I can implement a timer (Parse Cloud Code). The problem is it's returning a null value for the final execution time. I presume it has to do with not being able to retrieve the initial start variable.

How can I make that happen. Thanks!

```
var start;
var end;

exports.beginTimer = function beginTimer(functionName) {

    //Start timing now
    var start = new Date().getTime();
}

exports.endTimer = function endTimer(functionName) {

    //End timer
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    alert('Execution time for' + functionName + ': ' + time);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the keyword "var" in your method you create this variable in the namespace of the method itself.

Thats why in your "beginTimer" method your variable is already deleted at the end of the method block. So the easiest way to make your code work is to remove "var" from the variable declaration in your methods.

This will maybe occur new errors if you call multiple methods before finishing them because they will all use the same "start" and "end". You might want to think about using some kind of mapping between "functionName" and "start".

You could do this for example:

```
var start = {};

exports.beginTimer = function beginTimer(functionName) {

    //Start timing now
    start[functionName] = new Date().getTime();

}

exports.endTimer = function endTimer(functionName) {

    //End timer
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start[functionName];
    alert('Execution time for' + functionName + ': ' + time);
}
```

Since this could occur new problems when a method gets called twice before it already finished you might want to work with a unique identifier you pass to the method.

```
var start = {};

exports.beginTimer = function beginTimer(functionName, uid) {

    //Start timing now
    start[uid] = new Date().getTime();

}

exports.endTimer = function endTimer(functionName, uid) {

    //End timer
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start[uid];
    alert('Execution time for' + functionName + ': ' + time);
}
```

You would have to generate this UID in your method.

Comment: Thanks @jvecsei! I know this is out of the scope of this question, but would perhaps storing the provided function name and a local variable in a global dictionary work (to offset the issue you mention)?

Comment: I updated my answer, i hope this helps. When you're sure the one problem cant occur you dont need the UID.

Answer (score 3):

You've redeclared `start` and `end` within each function.

This masks the global variables with local variables of the same name.

`endTimer` gets `undefined` as the value of `start`.

Don't use `var` unless you want to create a locally scoped variable.

Comment: Wow such a noob mistake. Thank you.